# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception for an empty string on @RestQuery

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I have a handler in my rest easy lamda application
with the url: http://localhost:8080/store/search/v1/suggest

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> storeSearch(
      @RestHeader("id") String id,
      @RestQuery final String q,
      @RestQuery final String columns) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(q)) {
      logger.error("Search query is empty");
      return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
```

The app is doing well for below cases but failing if q is empty
http://localhost:8080/store/search/v1/suggest?q=ab
http://localhost:8080/store/search/v1/suggest

failing here
http://localhost:8080/store/search/v1/suggest?q=

Can you please suggest me what I am missing here.

Comment: Is this for Quarkus with RESTEasy Reactive?

Comment: Yes James. It is with Quarkus lamda application with RESTEasy Reactive.

Comment: Interestingly, The above issue occurs only on local environment and it is good in nonProd env and I just realized it. But I still wonder why it is the problem even in local environment.

Comment: Are they running the same version of Quarkus?

Comment: Yes, they both use same version of Quarkus.

Comment: It sounds like it would have to be environmental. No idea what that could be though.